# Why java asking me to block potentially unsafe components - all jars are signed

Tags: java, jar

I'm using special jar application to upload some files from hard disk (temp dir) to sftp, jars are signed by security certificate, always before upload, webbrowser is prompting with this window box:

Anyone has any idea how to remove this window (application is safe, all jars are signed, jar).?

[image]

Comment: What is your complete classpath?

Comment: The messages states '..contains both signed and unsigned code' You are probably referencing an unsigned jar file in the dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the solution suggested in this links below and see if it helps get past the error

http://java.com/en/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml

https://service.parachat.com/knowledgebase/113/Why-do-I-see-Error-Java-has-discovered-application-components-that-could-indicate-a-security-concern.html

Comment: no link-only answers please - they may disappear over time. Please quote the relevant parts here.